# Why my tabs and bottom menu has small size on tablets?

Tags: android

I'm running the app on a tablet and I'm seeing the Actionbar is small and also the Bottom menu / tabs have small size how do I increase the size? Is there any style for them that I can override? I did add some style for fitting the tabs into the tablet since they were smaller, how do I increase the size of the actionbar text and the menu/tabs?

### Edit

This is how it looks

[image]

I had to do this :

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
```

To show it on a tablet, but how's the name of the size?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the result you got?

Comment: @Marijan edited with my output

Comment: This looks like a normal size of the UI element for the tablet. If you compare it to other apps on the tablet, I'm pretty confident that they will be of the same size. Do you need to make it larger than natively defined?

Comment: Also for the tabs the size is smaller I guess.. (bottom ones)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the dimensions for the tablet
take a look at :

```
  values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi
  values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi
  values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi ,
                          5.1”  480x800 mdpi

  values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
  values-xxxhdpi          5.5"  1440x2560 xxxhdpi
  values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi,
                          4.65”  1280x720 xhdpi
  values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi,
                          3.7” 480x854 hdpi
  values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi
  values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi,
                          3.3” 240x400 ldpi,
```

Comment: check my edit please, where and what I have to add in values-sw720dp?

Comment: you have to create a folder values-sw720dp  under res
it will be res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml
in dimens.xml you have to specify action_bar_hg  
like this <dimen name="action_bar_hg ">100dp</dimen>
and then use it in your layout